# How to use an item variable inside a JSON query in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jmespath

I am trying to use an item variable inside a JSON query, but the result is an empty array.

below is the task defined for this action. But when i mention each value in the list separately in the place of item, I am getting proper value. The problem is only when I use the item variable.

```
    - name: Get the GP id of a Network with VLAN abc
      set_fact:
          gpmgmt: "{{gplist | json_query(\"[?Netid == `{{item}}`].{gpid: GP[?gpname == `GP-abc`].gpID}\")  }}"
      with_items: "{{ gpnet }}"
      register: gpidmgmt
```

Input JSON as below(gpnet):

```
[
    [
        "L_12345678",
        "N_59786432"
    ]
]
```

Input JSON as below(gplist):

```
[
    {
        "GP": [],
        "Netid": "L_12345678"
    },
    {
        "GP": [
            {
                "gpID": "103",
                "gpname": "GP-abc"
            },
            {
                "gpID": "102",
                "gpname": "GP-cde"
            },
            {
                "gpID": "101",
                "gpname": "efg"
            }
        ],
        "Netid": "N_59786432"
    }
]
```

```
Output as below
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "changed": false, 
            "msg": "All items completed", 
            "results": [
                {
                    "ansible_facts": {
                        "gpmgmt": []
                    }, 
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                    "changed": false, 
                    "failed": false, 
                    "item": "L_12345678"
                }, 
                {
                    "ansible_facts": {
                        "gpmgmt": []
                    }, 
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
                    "changed": false, 
                    "failed": false, 
                    "item": "N_59786432"
                }
            ], 
            "skipped": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `gpnet` is a list of list. You want to loop on the inside items. Either loop on the first element (`gpnet.0`) or on the flattened list if you have other elements (`gpnet | flatten`).

Comment: Doesn't `with_items` flatten lists by default? `flatten` is required (with levels) when used with `loop`.

Comment: Doesn't look like an issue with using `item` in query, I used `?Netid == 'L_12345678'` and it still returns `"gpmgmt": ""`.

Comment: Flatten option didnt work for me @Zeitounator

Comment: Netid with L_12345678 doesnot contain the gpname = GB-abc. S the result will be null. If you try with other Netid, you should get a result @seshadri_c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i it something like this you want?:

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    gpnet: [["L_12345678","N_59786432"]]
    gplist: [{"GP":[],"Netid":"L_12345678"},{"GP":[{"gpID":"103","gpname":"GP-abc"},{"gpID":"102","gpname":"GP-cde"},{"gpID":"101","gpname":"efg"}],"Netid":"N_59786432"}]
  tasks:
    - name: Get the GP id of a Network with VLAN abc
      set_fact:
        gpmgmt: "{{gpmgmt | d([]) + (gplist | json_query(query)) }}"  
      vars:
        query:  "[?Netid == '{{ item }}' ].{gpid: GP[?gpname == 'GP-abc'].gpID}"     
      loop: "{{ gpnet | flatten}}"
      register: gpidmgmt         

    - name: Print register
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ gpidmgmt }}" 

    - name: Print result
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ gpmgmt }}"
```

result:

```
TASK [Print register] ********************************
Sunday 07 November 2021  12:37:46 +0000 (0:00:00.058)   

ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
    changed: false
    msg: All items completed
    results:
    - ansible_facts:
        gpmgmt:
        - gpid: []
      ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      failed: false
      item: L_12345678
    - ansible_facts:
        gpmgmt:
        - gpid: []
        - gpid:
          - '103'
      ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      failed: false
      item: N_59786432

TASK [Print result] **********************
Sunday 07 November 2021  12:37:46 +0000 (0:00:00.094)

ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - gpid: []
  - gpid:
    - '103'
```

Comment: thank you @Frenchy. That works and I accept your solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm still very unsure about what you exactly want to get as a result (and you should definitely edit your question to add your precise expectation).

But based on the try by @Frenchy here is my take which does not involve `json_query` nor tasks or loops:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    gpnet: [["L_12345678","N_59786432"]]
    gplist: [{"GP":[],"Netid":"L_12345678"},{"GP":[{"gpID":"103","gpname":"GP-abc"},{"gpID":"102","gpname":"GP-cde"},{"gpID":"101","gpname":"efg"}],"Netid":"N_59786432"}]

    matching_gpids_list: >-
      {{
        gplist |
        selectattr('Netid', 'in', gpnet | flatten) |
        map(attribute='GP') |
        map('selectattr', 'gpname', '==', 'GP-abc') |
        map('map', attribute='gpID') |
        flatten
      }}

  tasks:
    - name: Show result
      debug:
        var: matching_gpids_list
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show result] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "matching_gpids_list": [
        "103"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Zeitounator. That works.